# Linq Split last part of the string

Tags: linq

I have a path "$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.xml" I would like to get the path minus "File.xml" i.e. "$/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3".

I have written the following method,

```
public string GetFilePathFromFolderPath(string serverPath)
    {
        var folders = serverPath.Split('/').ToList();

        folders.RemoveAt(folders.Count - 1);


        return folders.Aggregate(string.Empty,
                                 (current, folder) =>
                                 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(current)
                                     ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", current, folder)
                                     : string.Format("{0}", folder));
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

My Unit Test works fine but I would like to know if there is a simple way...

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void GetRootPathFromConfigFilePath_Validate()
    {
        var t = new Twrar();
        var a = t.GetFilePathFromFolderPath("$/Quan/Maa/CSr/mai.py");
        Assert.IsTrue(a == "$/Quan/Maa/CSr");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to use "/" as the path separator character even though it is "\" for Windows.

```
Dim s = "$/Quan/Maa/CSr///mai.py"
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(s).Replace("\"c, "/"c))
```

outputs `$/Quan/Maa/CSr`

*The following is Tarun Arora's edit:*

For C# this should be...

```
public string GetFilePathFromFolderPath(string serverPath)
    {            
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(serverPath).Replace("\\", "/");
    }
```

And all of my unit tests pass this...

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void GetRootPathFromConfigFilePath_Validate()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var a = t.GetFilePathFromFolderPath("$/Quan/Maa/CSr/mai.py");

        Assert.IsTrue(a == "$/Quan/Maa/CSr");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetRootPathFromConfigFilePath_SmallPath()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var a = t.GetFilePathFromFolderPath("$/Quan/mai.py");

        Assert.IsTrue(a == "$/Quan");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetRootPathFromConfigFilePath_RootPath()
    {
        var t = new TfsWrapper();
        var a = t.GetFilePathFromFolderPath("$/mai.py");

        Assert.IsTrue(a == "$");
    }
```

Comment: public string GetFilePathFromFolderPath(string serverPath)
{         
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(serverPath).Replace("\\", "/");
}

Comment: Works. I have added the C# equallent of the code and added a few unit tests to your solution. The edit is currently in review but should show up once approved.

Answer (score 0):

I have this method:

```
private static string GetPath(string fullPath)
{
    string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
    return fullPath.Replace(file, "");
}
```